# Como puedo repetir ultima instrucción realizada pasado unos segundos en un seudocodigo ? - pseint

Tags: algoritmos, pseint, pseudocódigo

Estoy tratando de realizar el juego de la serpiente (el mismo o similar que se encuentra en los nokia antiguos) usando pseint por medio de seudocodigo y no encuentro la forma de que la ultima instruccion realizada pasado unos segundos. Tengo entendido que puede usar la función 'Esperar' y 'Repetir', pero no se ocurre como unirlas.

He aqui el codigo

```
Algoritmo Snake
    Dimension m[20,20]
    Para fila<-1 hasta 20 con paso 1 hacer
        Para col<-1 hasta 20 con paso 1 Hacer
            m[fila,col]= " "
        FinPara

    FinPara


    Para i<-1 Hasta 15 Con Paso 1 Hacer  
        fila<-azar(19)+1
        col<-azar(19)+1
        m[fila,col]<-"X"
    Fin Para

    pf<-5
    pc<-5
    vivo="s"
    Mientras vivo="s" Hacer
        m[pf,pc]<-"~"
        Borrar Pantalla
        Escribir "===================="
        Para fila<-1 hasta 20 con paso 1 hacer
            Para col<-1 hasta 20 con paso 1 Hacer
                Escribir sin saltar m[fila,col]
            FinPara
            Escribir " "
        FinPara
        Escribir "===================="
        Mostrar"puntaje; ",punto

        Escribir sin saltar "Ingrese Opcion 2486"
        leer opcion
        Si opcion = "z" Entonces
            vivo = "n"

        Fin Si
        Si opcion = "4" Entonces
            pc<-pc-1
        FinSi
        Si opcion = "8" Entonces
            pf<-pf -1
        FinSi
        Si opcion = "6" Entonces
            pc<-pc +1
        FinSi
        Si opcion = "2" Entonces
            pf<-pf +1
        FinSi
    FinMientras


FinAlgoritmo
```

Alguna recomendacion?

Answer (score 1):

Para la función Esperar (similar a `sleep` de C), puedes establecer un tiempo en segundos específicos, por ejemplo, definiendo la variable

`segundos_espera <- 15;`

La función `Esperar segundos_espera;` automáticamente esperaría 15 segundos para continuar la ejecución.

Otra forma de usar esta función es con `Esperar Tecla;` que literalmente, espera que el usuario presione cualquier tecla para continuar.